# Angular2 Wrap components with login checks

Tags: angular, typescript

I have wrapped several components' ngInit with check to see if the users are logged in or not:

```
export class ComponentX implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
       if(this._authService.isLoggedIn()) {
          // Do stuff
       }
       else {
         // Redirect to loggin page
       }
    }
}
```

As I really don't want to repeat myself, I would like to move this if check to somewhere else that would be applied to the components I want it to.

How could I do that ?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Günter did suggest

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router'
import { AuthUtils } from "./authUtils.service"


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private _router: Router, private _authUtils: AuthUtils) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if(this._authUtils.isLogged()) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        this._router.navigate(["/login"])
        return false
    }
  }
}
```